# How to disable should.js override "should" property?

Tags: javascript, testing, should.js

One of the external libraries we're using is having a property called "should" in one of its classes.

When we run tests with [shouldjs](https://shouldjs.github.io/) it seems like should instruments its class with its "should" which crashes the library.

How can we hint shouldjs to avoid instrument this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to fill all posibilities.

You can require should.js via `should/as-function` and use it only as function, it will not try to extend `Object.prototype` in this case:

```
should(1).be.a.Number();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`should.noConflict`](https://shouldjs.github.io/#should-noconflict) to tell Should.js to use a different name than `should`. Should.js adds the name it uses to `Object.prototype`, which unsurprisingly can cause a bit of trouble...